# How to rectify this exception in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

Dear Friends,I am reading one text file and writing that content in one BasicEditField .If i try to type some thing in the editfield after writing the content of file, then it throughs a uncaught exception like "net_rim_plazmic_flint (126) is not responding,process terminated "can u  pls tell me what is this exception and how to solve this exception give some idea.
regards,
s.kumaran.

Answer (score 3):

This usually indicates that a Listener called by the the event thread is taking too long to return, or not returning at all. Any protracted processing, or methods that block waiting for an asynchronous event, can't run on the event thread.

Have a look at this [post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=16090).